# Convert String to Long in PIG Latin

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I am writing a script in Pig Latin to be run in PIG 0.15.0 over Hadoop 2.7.1 that obtains a list of JSON messages and treats the information in them. The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
    "var1": "xxx",
    "var2": "yyy",
    "var3": "zzz",
    "timestamp": "1448283242297",
}
```

I am loadingg the file with the following command:

```
rawdata = LOAD '/opt/test.json' USING JsonLoader('var1:chararray,var2:chararray,var3:chararray,timestamp: chararray');
```

When I try to convert the timestamp value using the ToDate function I get a format error, as it is receving an string, not a Long, so it expect a readable date.

```
indata = FOREACH rawdata GENERATE var1,var2,var3,ToDate(timestamp) as timel;


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1448283242297" is malformed at "2297"
```

I have read in the documentation that casting from String to Long is not supported. Is there a way to obtain de date from that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the optimal mode but I found a way of doing it. As you can call java methods from Pig Latin, just call the one that does the conversion:

```
define getLong InvokeForLong('java.lang.Long.parseLong','String');
rawdata = LOAD '/opt/test.json' USING JsonLoader('var1:chararray,var2:chararray,var3:chararray,timestamp: chararray');
indata = FOREACH rawdata GENERATE var1,var2,var3,ToDate(getLong(timestamp)) as timest;
```

And you get the correct result.

Comment: Very neat. This is definitely a feature of Pig that should be publicised more.